# DOMPDF - PHP Page to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have a PHP Page that is displaying a bunch of MongoDB documents information in a Table.
What I want to do is to make a button that print the current PHP Page (basically all the Table with CSS Style and Database variables) into a PDF.
But after trying a lot of code I still can't seem to make it work.

Here's my code right now

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

>>Here I have my code related to the MongoDB query

ob_start();
?>



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registre</title>
  </head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="submit" name="pdf" id="pdf" value="PRINT">
</form>
<table class="tftable">
    <thead>    
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($r as $document): 
        $bson = MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($document);
        $json = json_decode(MongoDB\BSON\toJSON($bson));
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $var1 ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $var2 ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var3 ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="var1">var1</label><br>
            <input type="date" id="var1" name="var1">
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="var2">var2</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="var2" name="var2">
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="var3">var3</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="var3" name="var3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Data"></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body></html>



<?php 
if(isset($_POST["pdf"])) {
    $html = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_flush();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream('registre.pdf',array('Attachment'=>1));
}
?>
```

Right now when I click the print, my PHP page looks like it is reloading itself quickly but nothing else happens and no PDF get shown.
If put the PHP part of the $dompdf before the HTML part, I get a blank PDF File.

PHP v8.0.5

dompdf v1.0.2

Thank you.

Comment: `ob_end_flush` might send the data - please try to use `ob_get_flush` instead of calling `ob_get_contents` and `ob_end_flush`

Comment: @NicoHaase Actually I just realised that the "reload" provoked an error at the bottom of my page telling me "Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent"

I tried with your solution but didn't help.
About this error I tried checking for any space left (didn't find any) and got rid of classes and style in the table but it didn't help.
I Tried removing the CSS file also thinking domPDF had a conflict with a line from it but same problem.

Comment: The "headers already sent" error is caused by the call to ob_end_flush. That tells the server to send the current buffer content to the browser. When you call `$dompdf->stream()` afterwards, Dompdf attempts to set the headers, which it can not do. You should call ob_end_clean() instead to ensure there is no content left in the buffer. After making these changes do you continue to see the same error after removing that function?

Comment: @BrianS Thank you ! That was it. I replaced ob_end_flush() by ob_end_clean() and now the PDF get printed ! Lines of the tables do not show, but it's ok I'll find the solutionon myself now that I have a PDF working !

Comment: added as an answer for posterity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "headers already sent" error is caused by the call to `ob_end_flush`. That tells the server to send the current buffer content to the browser. When you call `$dompdf->stream()` afterwards, Dompdf attempts to set the headers, which it can not do. You should call `ob_end_clean()` instead to ensure there is no content left in the buffer.